# Application of Deviation in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, mean, median, deviation

What would be the practical Application of Standard Deviation in JMeter?
I went throught practical applications of Mean, Media but did not understand the appropriate example for Deviation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition from Wiki.

> Standard deviation is a number used to tell how measurements for a group are spread out from the average (mean), or expected value. A low standard deviation means that most of the numbers are very close to the average. A high standard deviation means that the numbers are spread out.

How do I understand it?

It is important in finding how much variance is there from the mean. In real life standard deviation is used to find the probability of an anomaly (something crazy and unusual) happening.

Below link has very good example.

http://www.robertniles.com/stats/stdev.shtml